# dynamic colors in jquery circle-progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery circle-progress plugin and I want the color to be 3 colors according to usage, for example the colors should be orange from 0 to 10 and from 10 to 90 blue and red if 100 and the code is below

```
var c4 = $('.forth.circle');
c4.circleProgress({
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
    value: 0.1,
    size: 170,
    fill: { color: '#fc5201' }

});
```

Comment: This example does not look complete. Could you edit and add  more details, like the HTML used.

Comment: I have created a Fiddle from the Examples you referenced: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yn6t6cvg/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with the Gradient and it's not coloring segments of the circle, but the background. I got to this point: https://jsfiddle.net/yn6t6cvg/3/

This does not do exactly what you want, but maybe it will get you going in the right direction.

**HTML**

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="forth circle">
    <strong></strong>
    <span>custom angle, <br/> value update</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 6px 6px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.circle canvas {
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  background-color: #444;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font: 15px/1.3 Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle span {
  display: block;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var c4 = $('.forth.circle');

  c4.circleProgress({
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
    value: .75,
    size: 170,
    fill: {
      gradient: [ 
        ["red", .3],
        ["blue", .6],
        ["orange", .3]
      ],
      gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4 * 8.5,
    }
  });
});
```